# if statement always goes to the else

Tags: bash, scripting

I just started learning Bash scripting and i have to do a program that separate between one bit map image to two (the image is broken), I already found on the web how to write loops and statements
but i don't know why my if statement is always goes to the else.
the if is modulo by 2 thats equals to 0
here is the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
OUTPUT="$(hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X\n"' merge.bmp)"
echo $OUTPUT
vars=0
count=1
touch one
touch two
for i in $OUTPUT
    do 
    if (($vars%2==0))
    then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "2"
    fi
    vars=$((vars+count))
done
```

in the terminal the following error is

```
./q3.sh: 14: ./q3.sh: 2885%2==0: not found 

2
```

i really don't know why the `if` always print `2`

Comment: You use `/bin/sh` in your shebang, but `(( ... ))` is a Bashism. Use `/bin/bash` instead.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you but why is the shebang is matter (now the code is working) but why is he working now?

Comment: @SnirSudri, `/bin/sh` only guarantees a POSIX-compliant shell. `$(( ))` is part of the POSIX standard, but `(( ))` is not. See the "Choose Your Shell" section in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you, I will read this in a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

The shebang line is wrong, it should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

`((expression))` is a `bash` extension, not available in `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

The `/bin/sh` version of the `(())` bashism is this:

```
if test $(($vars % 2)) -eq 0; then
   echo "1"
   ...
fi
```

Since `$(())` knows about variable names, you may even drop the dollar and write

```
if test $((vars % 2)) -eq 0; then
   echo "1"
   ...
fi
```